# Replace NSNull Values in Array of Dictionary with empty string

Tags: ios, swift, nsdictionary

I have an array with a structure like this,

```
[
        {
            "Id": 20,
            "Name": "Name String",
            "Email": null 
       },
]
```

I want to replace the null occurrence with an empty string. I have tried the map method as below but no luck.

```
let tempResult = recordsList.map{ $0 is NSNull ? "" : $0 }
```

Comment: Please show how you declared `recordsList`?. In your current implementation, you are not comparing `email` as `nil` rather the whole object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your structure is an array of dictionaries.  When mapping, each element will be a dictionary.  Use that dictionary to construct a new dictionary where the `NSNull`s have been replaced by empty strings:

```
let recordsList: [[String : Any]] = [
        [
            "Id": 20,
            "Name": "Name String",
            "Email": NSNull()
       ]
]


let result: [[String : Any]] = recordsList.map { dict in
    var newdict = [String : Any]()
    for (k, v) in dict {
        newdict[k] = v is NSNull ? "" : v
    }
    return newdict
}

print(result)
```

> ```
> [["Email": "", "Id": 20, "Name": "Name String"]]
> ```

---

This can also be accomplished by using [`Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/3127165-init) and by mapping over the dictionary to change the nulls to empty strings:

```
let result: [[String : Any]] = recordsList.map { dict in
    Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: dict.map { (k, v) in (k, v is NSNull ? "" : v) })
}
```

Your question is tagged with `NSDictionary`.  That can be accommodated with a few changes:

```
let result: [NSDictionary] = recordsList.map { dict in
    Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: (dict as! [AnyHashable : Any]).map { (k, v) in (k, v is NSNull ? "" : v) }) as NSDictionary
}
```